# Overhead of Perfmon -> direct to SQL Database

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, performance-monitoring, remote-desktop-services, xenapp

HI All,

First up, I'm a total newb at Performance Monitoring. I'm looking to set up central performance monitoring of some boxes.

- 2K3 TS ( Monitor General OS Perf & Session Specific Counters )
- 2K8 R2 ( XenApp 6 = Monitor General OS Perf & Session Specific Counters )
- File Server ( Standard File I/O )

My ultimate aim is to get as many counters/information, without impacting the clients session experience at all. Including counters specific to their sessions.

I was thinking it logging directly to a SQL on another server, instead of a two part process of blg file then relog to sql.

Would that work ok? Does anyone know the overhead of going straight to SQL from the client?

I've searched around a bit, but havent found so much information it can be overwhelming.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We log from perfmon into SQL and have collected 10s of millions of datapoints this way. I've never noticed any appreciatable overheads, and it's great to have the data immediately available.

Comment: same opinion here.  Haven't noticed perf impact of remote perfmon on Server 2008 or newer.